# Горячие клавиши Zend Studio

Tags: zend-studio, ide

Подскажите мне, какими клавишами можно выполнять автодополнение? Например, постоянно приходится вводить **echo**, хотя окошко появляется, но tab не помогает, как не помогает ctr+space! И вообще, где можно почитать о шорткатах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему [тут](http://live.nsk.ru/2008/08/21/zend_studio_6_hotkeys/) всё понятно написано.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался уже, почитал в хэлпе, оказалось просто - enter. А сочетание ctr+shift+L у меня не работает, я переназначил раскладку клавы на ctr+shift. Да, иногда быстрее найти ответ в манах.